# Notify Item Inserted crashes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using this piece of code to add a new item when user clicks on the footer. however, the app crashes sometimes with the error showing invalid item position while at sometimes the item gets added. It was working properly with notifyDataSetChanged(). However, since that eats up the animation and is not efficient enough, so i reverted to notifyItemInserted()

```
if(adapter.getItemViewType(position)==3)
                    {
                            arrayList.get(position).isFooter = false;
                            arrayList.add(new Tasks("ggdgg",true));
                            adapter.notifyItemInserted(arrayList.size()-1);
                    }
```

Comment: Are you using the latest `support library`? `23.1.1`?

Comment: yes........................

Comment: i'm using a custom linearlayout manager. can it cause some problem? it is doing it's work perfectly fine,however and i need it to wrap the content of recyclerview.

Comment: It might... what sort of custom `LinearLayoutManager` you're using? Why don't you try to see if it also happens with a regular `LinearLayoutManager`?

Comment: happens with that also

Comment: error is with invalid position. indexoutofbound exception.

Comment: did you get a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Error with invalid position means there is a difference in the data list passed to the adapters and (`getItemCount` or `getItemViewType`).